# Cual es la sintaxis correcta de un procedimiento almacenado en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy intentando acceder a un procedimiento almacenado para  recorrerlo en una tabla pero me dice que la sintaxis es incorrecta
Alguien podria decirme donde esta el error

```
public function index()
    {
     
      $products = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(DB::raw("execute dbo.SP_Rep_Productos_QDisponible_Almacen_LoteSerie  @TipoReporte = 'A', @Producto = 'TM%', @Almacen = 'AT'"));
        return view('admin.tasks.index', compact('products'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner marcadores de `:nombre` para los parámetros y pasar un array que asocie cada marcador al valor.

Por ejemplo (usaré variables para que se vea más claro):

```
$sql="exec dbo.SP_Rep_Productos_QDisponible_Almacen_LoteSerie :TipoReporte, :Producto, :Almacen";
$params=array(':TipoReporte'=>'A',':Producto'=>'TM%',':Almacen'=>'AT')
$products = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(DB::raw($sql,$params));
```

Puedes usar también marcadores de posición `?`. Por ejemplo:

```
$sql="exec dbo.SP_Rep_Productos_QDisponible_Almacen_LoteSerie ?, ?, ?";
$params=array('A','TM%','AT')
$products = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(DB::raw($sql,$params));
```

El primer modo es un poco más verboso, pero es menos equívoco y más claro, porque sabes en todo momento a qué corresponde cada cosa.

Comment: Probe los 2 pero me dice sintaxis incorrecta :( SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Campo COUNT incorrecto o error de sintaxis (SQL: ejecutar dbo.SP_Rep_Productos_QDisponible_Almacen_LoteSerie ?, ?, ?) me sale este error nose a que se refiera realmente ya que la base de datos no la hice yo ni los SP entonces tampoco puedo ver como se realizaron

Comment: Probe algo asi  pero me dice true y no me arroja los arrays

Comment: ```public function index()
    {
        $products =   DB::connection("sqlsrv")->statement("exec dbo.SP_Rep_Productos_QDisponible_Almacen_LoteSerie  @TipoReporte = 'A', @Producto = 'TM%', @Almacen = 'AT'");
        dd($products);
        return view('admin.tasks.index', compact('products'));
    }```

Comment: @BrayanGalvan necesitaría ver tu SP, puede que la misma deba recibir una cantidad distinta de parámetros de los que se le están enviando y por eso el error, o que tenga un error de sintaxis en sí misma. [Aquí tienes instrucciones para ver la definición de una SP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/view-the-definition-of-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16).